# A problem with the path in a design

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path, cs6

George here
I have a problem with illustrator ... I accidently draw something with the paintbrush istead of doing it with the blob brush. Now my problem is that i wanted it to be a shape like line but now it has a path and i don't know how to or if I can make it without a path without the need of drawing it again... 
 Thank you for your time and I appreciate it if you respond.

Answer (score 1):

Select the path.

Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu.

That should convert the path to a shape.

If it didn't in one step, then choose `Object > Expand` from the menu as well.